# Dicom Pixeldata to UIImage

Tags: ipad, uiimage, dicom

Im trying to get a UIImage out of my dicom data on the ipad.

The Code looks like that:

```
reader->SetFileName(documentsFolderPath/test.dcm);
reader->Update();
ImageType *  imageTest = reader->GetOutput(); // get 2d image data
PixelType * pixelData = imageTest->GetBufferPointer();   

const void* buffer = pixelData;

// Set the dimensions of the current context
size_t width = 157; // set manually, but correct
size_t height = 143;

// 1 byte per component
size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
unsigned int multiplier;
bitsPerComponent *= 2; // short = 2 byte

size_t bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo;
CGDataProviderRef theDataProvider;
CFDataRef theDataReference;
bool shouldInterpolate = NO;
CGColorRenderingIntent theIntent;


bitsPerPixel = bitsPerComponent * 1; // because of grayscale image
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big;

// cg data provider to build the cg image
const UInt8* rawData = static_cast<const UInt8*>(buffer);

// For some reason initiating a CGImage uses BITS per pixel, so we need to divide by 8 to get BYTES 
// per pixel        
bytesPerRow = (bitsPerPixel/8) * width;

theDataReference = CFDataCreate(NULL,
                                rawData,
                                (bytesPerRow*height));

theDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(theDataReference);



// Finally create the image reference
CGImageRef theImageRef = CGImageCreate(width,
                                       height,
                                       bitsPerComponent,
                                       bitsPerPixel,
                                       bytesPerRow,
                                       colorSpace,
                                       bitmapInfo,
                                       theDataProvider,
                                       nil,
                                       shouldInterpolate,
                                       theIntent);


// Construct an output image
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:(theImageRef)];

imageView.image = myImage;
```

But my output image then looks like that:

http://www.ettisberger.ch/images/outputImage.png

(on a imageview with scale to fill, so the size doesnt matter)

But the background should be black and the most pixel of the bone are more or less white...

Is there someone who can see my fail?

EDIT: Could perhaps the 16bit on the ipad be a problem?

EDIT2:
I got a solution know. I go through every pixel and calculate a unsigned int value between 0 and 255. The max and min are the max and the min value of the whole picture, because we need to change the contrast.
It works, but my method needs 0.1-0.2 seconds to create one uiimage - and with a stack of 400 images its so slow and the user had to wait for 1 minute :/ Dont know if there is a better solution.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < (bytesPerRow*height);i++){
    short tmpPixelValue = *pixelData;
    short tmpNewPixelValue;

    if(tmpPixelValue == 0){
        tmpNewPixelValue = 0;
    }else{
        tmpNewPixelValue = (tmpPixelValue - min) * (255.0 / (max - min));
    }

    pixelBuffer[i] = (UInt8)tmpNewPixelValue;  

    pixelData++;
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about the dicom format, but it strikes me as odd to use kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big for 16 bit image data. Have you tried changing that to kCGBitmapByteOrder16Big?

Comment: Thank you for your hint - I really thought that it could be the problem - but now im at home and it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what your EDIT2 suggested is that you are applying a window-level & window-width to your images.  This is often required to process anything higher than 8 bits.  To speed what your EDIT2 has now, you can always build a look-up table for pixels with similar intensity that have already been computed once before.

Say, your original pixel has a value of 1255, and upon your window-level & window-width computation, your finally output maybe 123 (just an example, depends on ur level and width).  Then whichever subsequent pixels with original value of 1255, it will automatically be recognized as 123 (and this should save you some time as we know, computations will take more time than looking up an array).

** FYI: max, min should be associated with window width and window level (one of the most straightforward implementation is: max = window level + (window width / 2), and min = window level - (window width / 2).  Or, you can follow the DICOM standard, but i forgot which chapter, try Grayscale Softcopy Presentation State.

Comment: Hey Gary, thanks for your answer. I found out, that the main problem wasnt the calculation - it was the loading through the ITK framework. I know use ITK iterators and I could bring down the loading time from 50-60sec to 30 :)

But another question. I changed my max and min to the calculation with window level and width. On the most dicom stacks I load its totally right - but at one example the colors are totally wrong :o

Is my calculation right? ==>
            tmpNewPixelValue = (tmpPixelValue - min) * (255.0 / (max - min));

Comment: For colors, do you mean the grayscale values?

Comment: Yes, the grayscale values. The caculated max and min values are the same as I open the dicom in the osirix viewer.

Comment: Well, the pixel representation(as set in the dicom header) of this dicom stack is signed short, not unsigned. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Likely.  One more test though, Osirix reports the pixel's original value in their annotation section (x, y, value).  Does your match theirs?

Comment: Hi Gary, sry for the late answer. I checked now the pixel value of my iterators get() and the pixel value of the osirix. Its exactly the same. So the pixel values im getting are correct. Also the max and min values are like in osirix.

But perhaps is my calculation to change the 16bit values in a 8bit from 0 to 255 with including the max and min false? Is there some documentation how this works?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray myself, but is it possible that it is looking for RGBA values, where R,G,B are 0-255 and all the same?  If that's the case, you will need to convert the input to a 4 component data structure.  Going from 16 bit float to 255 char can be calculated as I have provided at

[How to translate DICOM image width and level to JPEG brightness and contrast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858586/how-to-translate-dicom-image-width-and-level-to-jpeg-brightness-and-contrast)

Comment: Hey Michael, I have a solution know, it is in my answer post :) It works, but a little bit too slow at the moment, because I load stacks with 400+ dicom slices and that uses ca 1min to load a whole dicom on the ipad

Comment: Hey Michael, I looked at your answer in the link, because I think know that my problem with one dicom has to do with your answer. You said that there are other factors to convert pixel data(as ex. photometric interpretation) which are important. Where can I find a good documentation about that? Because only one dicom doesnt look good on my ipad, but the others are fine. I think now that my calculation fails sometimes.

Comment: Figuring out the reason was pretty much trial and error for me.  I'd start here for more info about photometric interpretation: http://www.medicalconnections.co.uk/wiki/Photometric_Interpretations