# Set "window level" of a png (converted from DICOM)

Tags: java, image, png, dicom, imagej

So, there is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858586/how-to-translate-dicom-image-width-and-level-to-jpeg-brightness-and-contrast) here on SO about changing the window level of a DICOM converted into JPG.

But I have files that were converted from DICOM to PNG (32 bits) and I am supposed to make it be displayed with these properties:

> (0028,1050) WindowCenter       DS    # 6          1  [382.0]
>
> (0028,1051) WindowWidth        DS    # 6          1  [672.0]

I couldn't really understand how to relate those to a PNG.

```
//(I am using Java and ImageJ but wouldn't mind using a third party tool for this)
```

**What kind of operations I have to perform on the PNGs to meet such criteria?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [PS 3.3](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/2014a/output/pdf/part03.pdf) section C.11.2.1.2 of the DICOM Standard for explanation of Window Center and Window Width. This section includes pseudo code showing how to apply Window Level to extended grayscale image (e.g. over 8 bits per pixel gray value in the pixel data element). 
Also, note that you may need to apply the Modality LUT transformation if dataset contains Rescale Slope (0028, 1053) and Rescale Intercept (0028, 1052) before applying the VOI LUT transformation (e.g. applying Window Center and Window Width). Please refer to table C.11-1b under section C.11.1 for information on how to apply Modality LUT transformation.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the program used to write the DICOM to a png. A lookup table should be applied to the pixels in the PixelData tag to create the image to be displayed. You can check if it is doing this as you want.

Assuming the bit depth in you DICOM is greater than 8 (pixels may be over 255) you will loose information transferring the image to 32 bit PNG since the pixels will all range from 0 to 255.

If the creation of the images is exact then the PNG image should be equal to the PixelData values after applying the lookup. In your case all pixels below 382-672/2 should be zero. Those greater than 382+672/2 should be the maximum value (255) and a linear lookup should be applied in between. Since there is 672 values (>255) you will not get the PNG to match the DICOM as it should be displayed but may be sufficient for your purposes.